# export double quotes using template

Tags: go

I'm using `template` to export `"` in go but it returns only `&#34;`. Is there a way to get it to export `"` instead.

```
import (
    "html/template"
)

//Testf  a test function
func Testf() string {
    return "\""
}

//MapToFunctions Map actions to functions
var MapToFunctions = template.FuncMap{
    "testf":      Testf}
```

Then, to use in a file, I'd put `{{ testf }}`

Comment: Have it return a `template.HTML` instead and return `template.HTML("\"")`. 
 https://golang.org/src/html/template/content.go?s=1375:1386#L25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `html/template` will make it html safe which escapes all the html special characters and replacing them with html encoding.

In order to avoid that, you should replace `html/template` with `text/template`

[text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)